# Woocommerce Additional Products now showing

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I am building a Woocommerce site and am having some issues.

On the category page, it shows the 15 products and at the bottom it has a link to view additional products. When you click on the page number, it should show the products on that page, but it does not go anywhere.

I have not been able to figure out why, I have actvated different templates, deactivated all plugins and removed all scripts in the header and none of them fix it.

The URL is `http://198.143.189.211/~utahball/?product_cat=birthday-bouquets`

If there are any ideas, it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the link is malformed. When I click on "2" for the 2nd page, the link is:

```
http://198.143.189.211/~utahball/?product_cat=birthday-bouquets#038;paged=2
```

Everything from the # gets treated as an anchor on the URL prior to the #, meaning, the browser is looking for an anchor called "038;paged=2" on

```
http://198.143.189.211/~utahball/?product_cat=birthday-bouquets
```

which is obviously just page 1. The correct URL for page 2 should be:

```
http://198.143.189.211/~utahball/?product_cat=birthday-bouquets&paged=2
```

Comment: Oh jeeze! Something I should have tried first. I realized that, but when I read your response I realized I needed to change the permalinks. Worked!